# I need a custom field that will count the item line in transaction page while on Edit mode in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, setvalue

How can I make my script work? The goal is to have a custom field that will count the line items in Deposit page while on Edit mode.
Please note that I am an accountant and interested in learning javascript so my script is a mess.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord'], currentRecord => {
  
        test_set_getValue: () => {
            // Get a reference to the currently active record
            let myRecord = currentRecord.get();

            var numLines = objRecord.getLineCount({
                sublistId: 'item'
               });

            // Set the value of a custom field
            myRecord.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_ns_acs_item_count',
                value: numLines
            });
        },

        return {
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
        };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script was copied from a couple of different places.

For a bank deposit you need to use the correct sublines ids.

See the data dictionary for [deposits](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/deposit.html)

try:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define([], () => {
  
        function beforeSubmit(ctx){
            // Get a reference to the currently active record
            let myRecord = ctx.newRecord;

            const subLines = (sublist)=>{
                const lineCount = myRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:sublist});
                return lineCount == -1 ? 0 : lineCount;
            };

            // Set the value of a custom field
            myRecord.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_ns_acs_item_count',
                value: subLines('cashback') + subLines('other') + subLines('deposit')
            });
        },

        return {
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
        };
});
```

Comment: Haha, that's currently how I am trying to learn javascript. Appreciate your help but the script did not work.

I've an updated script but the value that shows up is different from what I am expecting.

Comment: If this is a bank deposit then your sublists are different and there are potentially 3 of them. I've updated the answer

Comment: Yes, it is a bank deposit transaction. I've reuploaded the script but it still doesn't work. Not sure where the error is. When I edit the Deposit record and click the deposit checkbox, add another transaction line in Other Deposits or cashback, the field wont update. Really appreciate your help. The field is blank the entire time.

Comment: The field won’t be populated until you save the deposit

Comment: Is it possible to set it to update on Edit mode?

Comment: Also the script doesn't count the payments that were checked in payments subtab. :( I tried to use payment instead but it counts all payments available even unchecked

Comment: That would be a client script and much more complex than this.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for being patient and all your help!